# How to fix an error in Antlr4-generated Lexer class?

Tags: c#, antlr4

I am using antlr-4.13.0-complete.jar to generate C# parser and lexer classes for the grammar. Then I am using these classes in C# console app, with Nuget Package Antlr4.Runtime.Standard, version 4.13.0.
I am getting compile-time error in the lexer class:

```
    private void DATE_action(RuleContext _localctx, int actionIndex) {
        switch (actionIndex) {
        case 0: 4 break;
        }
    }
```

Error   CS1002  ; expected
It points to the column after "4"

To generate the c# classes I am using following bat file, specifying my grammar as argument:

```
java -jar d:\Libraries\Antlr4\4130\antlr-4.13.0-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp %*
```

My grammar:

```
schedule: (dateSpec | exceptionSpec)*;

...
DATE: DAY '/' MONTH '/' [0-9]{4};
HOUR: ('0' [0-9] | '1' [0-9] | '2' [0-3]);
MINUTE: [0-5] [0-9];
DAY: [1-9] | '1' [0-9] | '2' [0-9] | '3' [0-1];
MONTH: ('0' [1-9] | '1' [0-2]);
```

The question is:
What to do in this situation, correct the error manually, or report it here? May be something else?
Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include de antlr rule(s) that generate this class

Comment: I edited the question, added the grammar and the command that I use to generate the classes

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any antlr, but this seems not right to me: `[0-9]{4}` this looks like a regex not an antlr rule

Comment: Note, your grammar will not work for other reasons. DAY and MONTH overlap in recognition, so '1/1/2023' will not tokenize correctly: '1' tokenizes to DAY. Antlr lexers follow two basic rules: (1) The rule that matches the longest input "wins"--regardless of how the lexer rules are ordered, regardless of how you parser is trying to parse. Lexers work independently from the parser. (2) If two or more rules match the same input, then the first one listed in the .g4 "wins".

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> DATE: DAY '/' MONTH '/' [0-9]{4};
> ```

Curly braces don't signify repetition in ANTLR, they signify actions, i.e. code that should be executed when the rule is matched. So in this case you're saying the code `4` should be executed when the `DATE` rule is matched, which is why the `4` ends up in the generated C# code. But `4` by itself is not a legal C# statement and that's why you get a syntax error.